# Java Compile time interface changes

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java, and have inherited an existing android app.  The original developer has chosen to use an Interface for Constants.

My problem is that I need to change a number of these constants to compile the App for Production vs Dev.  Everything works just fine if I modify a handful of values by hand, but that is just an ugly way to handle this, and I will probably make a mistake one day.

So, my goal is to find a solution that can be transparent to the remainder of the code, and use a single Constant to toggle back and forth between dev and production.

Sample of existing Code:

```
package package.common;
public interface Consts {

    // Define the Build Type
    boolean PRODUCTION_BUILD = false;

    String BASE_URL   = "https://domain.com/Dev/Mobile.ashx";

    interface RSA {
        String PUBLIC_KEY_SHA1 = "....";
    }

}
```

and used like this

```
import package.common.Consts;

public class HttpsConn extends NetConnection {

    String url = Consts.BASE_URL;

}
```

Is there a way to use a CONSTANT to modify this Interface at compile time?  Or am I going to have to bit the bullet and modify the code that uses this interface as part of the solution?

Comment: This demonstrates one of many reasons to use interfaces (and actually _use,_ not just throw constants into). If you changed the code to use _methods_ that return the needed values, instead of straight-up constants, you could simply define two implementations of the `Consts` interface: one for dev, and one for prod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can write this in `Consts`

```
boolean PRODUCTION_BUILD = false;
String BASE_URL = PRODUCTION_BUILD ? "..." : "...";
```